# Qt: Using default model for selecting my data

Tags: model-view-controller, qt

I am quite new to Qt and am in a situation where I want to use a model for my needs:
I have a dynamic number of instances of a subclass that need to be handled differently (different UI controls for each if it is selected). I want to get a list view where I can add new elements or delete old ones, as well as disabling/enabling existing ones.

Of course I want to rewrite as least of the code as possible, so I thought of utilizing the Listwidget and a ListModel to give some controls to the user. But how to link these (or better the items) to instances of the classes?

Do you know any tutorials on this? 
I already looked in QtDemo and Google but I do not know the right words to search for
so I had no good results.

Basically what I think I need is a model item that accepts `Collider*` for its data.
But when I plug this into `QStandardItem.setData()` it says `error: ‘QVariant::QVariant(void*)’ is private`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution to this problem.
As `QStandardItem`s are capable of storing `QVariant`s as data I wanted to store a pointer to my data in a `QVariant`. To achieve this I had to use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyType*)`.
With this I was able to

```
MyType *MyInstance = new MyType;
QVariant data;
data.setValue(MyInstance);
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem("My Item");
item->setData(data);
standardModel->appendRow(item);
```

And the best is you can add as many types you want and let `QVariant` do the work to decide if it contains the type you wanted:

```
if(v.canConvert<MyType*>())
 //Yes it is MyType
else if( v.canConvert<MyOtherType*>())
    //Oh it is the other one
```

So finally this only requires to declare the meta type so you do not have to subclass any items.

Also you should read on the limitations of this here:
[Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)
[qRegisterMetaType](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType)

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/model-view-programming.html) page answer your questions? There's an example of deriving a StringListModel item that you might be able to use as a template

Comment: It has been a while now, sorry for the late answer to your answer: That describes what I wanted to avoid. There are many examples where you just need to assign a pointer as data to an item which should be supported without subclassing. Fortunately it seems I have found a solution which I am going to post here.